# How to get rid of "fringes" in 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The code below generates a plot with some ugly "fringes".  Is there a way to get rid of them and get a smoother graphic?

```
a = 2.3;
myGray = Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[1]];
s1 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, a, 0} + {x, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], y}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
s2 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, -a, 0} + {x, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], y}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
s3 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0.8 a} + {x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
s4 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, -0.8 a} + {x, y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
s5 = ParametricPlot3D[{a, 0, 0} + {Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
s6 = ParametricPlot3D[{-a, 0, 0} + {-Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100];
Show[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> {-2.1, -2.4, 1.1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict `x` and `y` to `Disk[]` using `RegionFunction`:

```
s1 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, a, 0} + {x, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], y}, 
  {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> (#3^2 + #4^2 <= 1 &), Mesh -> 21, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> myGray, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Doing the same for `s2` thru `s6` we get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The fringes stem from the fact that the disk is discretized into a triangle mesh and its boundary edges are not very short (and the fact that $\sqrt{1 - r^2}$ is not differentiable at the point $r =1$). You can avoid this, e.g., by using a different parameterization:

```
s1 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, a, 0} + {r Cos[t], Sqrt[1 - r^2], r Sin[t]},
  {r, 0, 1}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
  Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, 
  PlotPoints -> 100
  ]
```

Comment: Or usual parametrization of hemisphere: `ParametricPlot3D[{0, a, 0} + {Sin[f] Cos[t], Cos[f], Sin[f] Sin[t]}, {f,0,Pi/2}, {t,-Pi,Pi}, Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> myGray, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: Thanks, but the point is to show this specific parametrization; it's for a textbook.

Answer (score 3):

`ImplicitRegion[]` works better than `Disk[]` (but why?):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2.3, 0, 0} + {Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], x, y},
 {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}], Mesh -> 21, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1] &), 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

*Update:*
Another approach is to control the discretization of the `Disk[]`, the boundary being the most important element in this problem:

```
disk = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], MaxCellMeasure -> "Length" -> 0.001];
disk = DiscretizeRegion[disk];

ParametricPlot3D[{0, 2.3, 0} + {x, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], y},
 {x, y} ∈ disk, Mesh -> 21, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (White &), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I can only accept one of the answers... :(

Comment: @Frunobulax You're welcome, and that's the way it is.  I added an alternative method, BTW.